# Objective-c Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to make an application and that have an login screen.When user press login I'm posting username and password to my webservice.After That I'm sending tokens,name and adress informations.I need the keep this informations in device then fetch them in another  views.How can I do that ? Do you know any resource about that.

Thank You

Comment: Have a look at [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html). This may suit your needs.

Comment: To avoid future downvotes share what you have tried and what research you have done towards solving your question, like links to other questions and websites.

Comment: Use `NSUserDefaults` or `Core-Data`. There are lots of answers on SO and tutorials on google. Try them and then ask if you have any problem.

Comment: @Murat you can try to use .Plist for it.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answers I'm trying to use .plist and NSUserDefaults now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing so, and CoreData is one of them.

I suggest you look for information about how to implement and use core-data instead of asking a tutorial on SO. Googling something like "CoreData tutorial" will give you many good examples :) It should take you up to 6 hours to get it in place comfortably.

Though you suggested CoreData, I'd like to suggest something else, because that kind of data can be stored very easily in the `NSUserDefaults`, also known as `Preferences`. That way is the fastest and easiest but has its downsides, the biggest one would be that it's not a model and doesn't use a database, it's just an XML file (`.plist`) that is loaded every time. Because it's the credentials of the user I assume you're gonna need it every time so it's okay to store that in that `NSUserDefautls` file.

Code is simple :

Save in the `NSUserDefaults` :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"myString" forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Get from the `NSUserDefaults` :

```
NSString *myString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

To remove an object you can just set the object to `nil` for the key you want to remove.

Also, note that you can not store custom objects in there, but only types that you could store in a .plist file. You can find them if you go in your info.plist in your project and see what the IDE allows you to create from there. I think they're limited to (but check where I said to be sure ) : string, array, dictionary, number, boolean, data, and I feel like i'm forgetting one so I'll leave an edit later. But with these you can store your credentials easily, as strings I would guess.